# Drupal | Uncached JS cookie/tracking code algorithm in cached pages

Tags: javascript, variables, caching, drupal

I use "Tracking Code" module (https://www.drupal.org/project/tracking_code) to add my tracking snippets.

I add these codes to the `After <BODY>`.

I also have my own tracking cookie, which carries `userID`.

**GOAL:** 
Set the `userID` to each tracking code snippet

**PROBLEM:** I have my cache enabled, so these snippet codes are cached. This means I cant parse cookies with PHP and set global js variables, which would be accessible in each snippet.

**SOLUTION:**
Parse cookie with javascript, so even if code is cached, variables would still be updated.

**PROBLEM:** 
Usual drupal JS, like:

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.user_cookie = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
   ...
     //Im getting some variables from PHP here and using them
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Gets executed too late, which means variables defined there are not available in the tracking code snippet.

**SOLUTION:** Using the following code, I can set js variables and they can be accessed from the snippet

```
(function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {
   // Is executed on time!
   // How to get variables from php here??
})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
```

**PROBLEM:** I can no longer get some static variables (which can be cached) from PHP, using the code:

```
function user_cookie_page_build(&$page) {
  drupal_add_js(array('user_cookie' => array('someVariable' => $someValue)), 'setting');
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'user_cookie') . '/js/user_cookie.js');
}
```

**SOLUTION (WORKAROUND):** Executing inline script in `head` sets the variables, but I don't like this way.

```
  drupal_add_js( 'Drupal.user_cookie.cookieName = "'
                . variable_get('user_cookie_fname') . '";',
      array(
          'type' => 'inline', 
          'scope' => 'head',
          'weight' => 0
      )
  );
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'ft_user_cookie') . '/js/ft_user_cookie.js');
```

If anybody has a better solution (Ajax is not the way in my case), let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured one workaround, but its not a perfect solution:

```
  drupal_add_js(  'Drupal.ft_user_cookie.cookieName = "' . 
                   variable_get('user_cookie_fname') . '";',,
      array(
          'type' => 'inline', 
          'scope' => 'head',
          'weight' => 0
      )
  );
```

Adding this before my script

```
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'ft_user_cookie') . '/js/ft_user_cookie.js');
```

Solves the problem.